# How to skip a relationship and use other relationship based on where clause in a query using same query data in laravel 8

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I want to use if else in a query but using the data of this query using where clause

Comment: Have you tried using `when($boolean, $callback)`?

Comment: I want to add when($boolean, $callback) condition on relationship please can u guide me

Answer (score 0):

If you want to conditionally eager load a realtionship, you can use `when(condition, callback)` in your query.

```php
$query = YourModel::query()
    ->when($something == true, function ($query) {
        $query->with('relationship')
    })
```

Comment: ok but I want to add the when() function on the relationship, not on the main model